# Issue with jQuery Tabs CSS in IE6

Tags: css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-6

This is the website in question: http://www.ai-ad.com/2010Cwb/insidePage.html

The issue is with the bottom left jQuery UI Tabs (there are five tabs named : 淡水、陽明山、基隆、烏來、石門水庫)

In IE 6, when I move the cursor to other tabs, the content height under the tab will change.

I don't really know why, I thought it could a problem with jQuery UI's CSS, but I had tried many way, it still the same.

Can someone helps me to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

> This is the website in question:
>   http://www.ai-ad.com/2010Cwb/insidePage.html
>   The issue is with the bottom left jQuery UI Tabs
>   (there are five tabs named : 淡水、陽明山、基隆、烏來、石門水庫)
>   In IE 6, when I move the cursor to other tabs, the
>   content height under the tab will change.

It seems to require a few lines of javascript in order to
"tame" the "misbehaved" way that IE6 renders certain CSS
code.

Albert in Manila

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by setting tabs height to 100%;

```
$(".tabs").each(function(){
    $(this).css("height","100%");
    $(this).tabs();
});
```

Comment: In my case the problem was specifically with IE6 and when the tabs had collapsible panels in them - IE6 was having trouble calculating the height of the tab with the collapsible stuff in it. I was about to have to disable the functionality for dear old IE6 users (most of my customers), so thanks for the fix. In my case I only have one set of tabs so I just set the CSS to 100% before tabifying it and it's done.